# How can I authenticate user and how can I get first name and second name of user according to the login person?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-sql-database

Below is my login function, I want to change the following:

1. differentiate between admin login and user login to show different page layouts
2. get the user's first name and second name according to the login user

please how can I do that any suggestion or examples?

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(Customers customer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await _context.Customers.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Email == customer.Email && m.Password == customer.Password);
            if (user != null)

            {
                

                return RedirectToAction("Account", "Account");
            }
            else 
            {
                ViewBag.error = "Login Failed";
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
```

Comment: _Please_ don't tell me that you're storing the plaintext password in the database.

Comment: ***never ever ever ever*** store passwords as plain-text! ***hash them!*** (the _only_ valid exception is for educational purposes; to demonstrate how bad it is to store passwords as plain-text.)

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to maintain ***Role*** column values in login table in DB.
- Add values to the Role column Ex : Admin Role - 1 , User - 0
- Change the login procedure to return the Role,FirstName,LastName instead of count

```cs
Select Role,Password,FirstName,LastName from Users where Username=@Username and Password=@Password
```

- After authenticating the user(valid authentication, if password matches), redirect to the View based on the role.

```cs
if (Validate_User(Customers customer))
{
    if (customer.Role == "1")
    {
        return View("AdminView");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("UserView");
    }
    ViewBag.FirstName=customer.FirstName;
    ViewBag.LastName=customer.LastName;
}
else
{
    //handle failed login    
     ViewBag.error = "Login Failed";
     return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
```

Please refer [Role Based Access](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/role-based-access-of-an-mvc-application/)